# Specialize a template class to behave like a float in one case

Tags: c++, templates, alias, template-specialization

So, imagine a vector class:

```
template <size_t size>
class Vector<size> {
    std::array<float, size> data;
    .... 
}
```

Is there a way to specialize the template to be a float if the size is 1?
Something like:

```
// The case of a Vector with size 1 should behave like a float
template <>
using class Vector<1> = float;
```

I want to apply that to other classes too.
For example, treating a Matrix with column size 1 to be a Vector with the size of its rows.

---

Thanks in advance for the help :)

Comment: Have you tried armadillo http://arma.sourceforge.net ?

Comment: I don't know if you can make `Vector<1>` an alias for `float` but you can have an `operator float&` that is only available for `Vector<1>`.

Comment: @Minor Threat I'm writing my own math library for use of education, learning and playing around with it, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Adding an `operator float&` is nice. Replacing the whole thing with a `float` is a bad idea. If `Vector<2>::size()` exists, then `Vector<1>::size()` should exist as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a dedicated template for type selection (note that partial specializations are not permitted for alias templates so there is no way to get away with just one template):

```
template<size_t size> struct
VectorType{ using type = VectorImpl<size>; }; // VectorImpl is your current Vector

template<> struct
VectorType<1>{ using type = float; };

// alias template
template<size_t size> using
Vector = typename VectorType<size>::type;
```

Comment: Thanks that seems to work quite nicely.
I guess I just hoped for a shorter solution like the one idea in my original question.

Answer (score 2):

I can not check it right now. Maybe in a way like below.

```
template <>
class Vector<1> {
  float n;
 public:
  operator float& () { return n; }
}
```

May be you need implement other required operators.

Comment: Seems like a possibility to me, thanks for that.
However, it will still call functions that accept a Vector of any size rather than call the overloaded version with float right?

Comment: I am not sure. I assume in this case ambiguity error can be reported. Or exact float match shall be selected rather than a template function for a vector of any size.

Comment: It will indeed call functions that accept `Vector` if available. It does not do implicit conversion for cases when an exact match exists.

Comment: @patatahooligan thanks, I hoped on cutting out on some performance loss with that and simplify some things, I guess I have to take VTT's solution for that.

Comment: @SirHeadshot: This idea won't cause performance loss. You must have something else causing that.

Comment: @MooingDuck I just guessed so, because calling, for example, matrix multiplication will call the vector multiplication N times (where N is the number of columns of the rhs matrix).
My thought was if I could define Matrix<rows, 1> simply as Vector<1>, I would save the extra step of calling matrix multiplication with a matrix

Answer (score 0):

Your original code would probably violate [One-Definition Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule), but I believe this could be fairly equivalent and relatively short alternative:

```
template <std::size_t N>
struct VectorImpl {
   std::array<float, N> data;
};

template <std::size_t N>
using Vector = typename std::conditional<(N == 1), float, VectorImpl<N>>::type;
```

[[live demo]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jdumx1k6N3gujolY)